# How do I communicate the form parameters from the template to the route in ember.js?

Tags: forms, ember.js

I have a form like this in a template:

```
<form {{action 'add' on='submit'}}>

<label for="name">Name</label>
{{input value=name placeholder='Enter name' required="required"}}
</form>
```

Then I have the following route:

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        add: function() {
            alert(this.get('name'));
        }
    }
});
```

The alert is fired, but the output is "undefined". I tried to create a model in the route, but it didn't help. What am I missing to get the alert to show the string I type in the form? I don't want to use a controller, since controllers are [discouraged](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgycDZjOnIg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. About Controllers**

If you do not like to use controllers this would work for you (but I **do not recommend** you to follow this way):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    add: function() {
        alert(this.controllerFor( this.get('routeName') ).get('name'));
    }
  }
});
```

In fact, if you use `name` in template:

```
{{input value=name}}
```

you are actually using controller property `name`.

So there is **suggestion** to use triples (route, controller, template) for every route, and in future triples could be transformed to routing components. You could read about it here:

https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97

**2. Data communication**

I'd suggest you to **use `model` for data** communication. You could define `model` hook in route:

```
// route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     // your logic here, for example
     // return Ember.Object.create({name: 'DefaultName'});
     // or
     // return this.store.createRecord('yourModel', {name: 'DefaultName'}); 
   }
});
```

then you'll have `model` property in controller, you could use it in template

```
 // template
 <form {{action 'add' on='submit'}}>
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   {{input value=model.name placeholder='Enter name' required="required"}}
 </form>
```

then you could place your action in controller:

```
// controller
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  action: {
    add: function() {

      // whatever you'd like to do with model, for example
      // alert( this.get('model.name') );
      // or
      // var self = this;
      // this.get('model').save().then(function() {
      //   self.transitionToRoute('someRoute');
      // });
    }
  }
});
```

You could also place action in route, but then you have to write:

- `this.modelFor('yourRouteName')` to get `model`,
- `this.controllerFor('yourRouteName').get('someProperty')` to get controller property `someProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is a "correct way", but this might help: `this.controller.get('name')`